How to sing a tone and be sure?
For example I want to sing a C and then a D a capella (or for example a F then a G) whatever you want be a tone...
How can I be sure that I sang a tone  by ear only ?
I know it's relative pitch but how to check by myself ?

Play it on an instrument immediately after singing it. Vocalists practice at a piano often, checking pitches from time to time.

The obvious answer would be to use a pitch pipe, or a keyboard instrument if one is handy.  In this smartphone age, there is countless app that can be a virtual piano.
Please make the question more explicit so that you can get a more targeted answer that you want, if such a device / an instrument is not feasible in your situation.

I have heard singers who were 100% sure, they knew they were on pitch, even though they were horribly off pitch. Maybe I was wrong? Maybe you could use some kind of a measurement device. Record your singing and let a computer analyze the pitches?

Simple way is to reference the two notes against the same interval that you know in a song. Or use tonic sol-fa, where you already know the intervals' sounds from the note names. Of course, you won't know for sure whether they are the actual pitch notes, unless you have absolute pitch, but I don't think that's what you are asking.
